# If C and D are independent $P(C)=P(D)$ and $P(CD)=P(D^c)$. What is $P(C)$

Tags: probability

If C and D are independent $P(C)=P(D)$ and $P(CD)=P(D^c)$. What is $P(C)$

I'm having trouble figuring this out I was able to work through and get these equalities which are true given the constraints

$$P(C)P(D)=P(CD)=P(D)^2=P(C)^2$$
$$P(D^c)=1-P(D)=P(CD)=P(C)P(D)$$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

We have $$1-P(C)=P(C)^2$$

Let $x=P(C)$, this is a quadratic equation.

That is you just have to solve for $$1-x=x^2$$

and choose the solution that is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: how do you find the solutions?

Comment: you can complete the square or use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)